# Why is the value in the loop never greater than 2?

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I have the loop below, the value of `unique` is never greater than `2`. `n` is the total number of integers in the array (I read integers from a file line by line).

I am completely stumped and have been for a long time. Why is the value of `unique` never greater than `2`?

```
int last = array[0];
int unique = 1;
int i;

for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (array[n] != last) {
        last = array[n];
        unique++;
        printf("i:%d\n", i);
        printf("n:%d\n", n);
        printf("last:%d\n:", last);
    }
}
printf("unique:%d\n", unique);
```

OUTPUT:

```
 i:1
n:9
last:0
:unique:2
 i:1
n:4
last:4
:unique:2
 i:1
n:5
last:4
:unique:2
 i:1
n:5
last:4
:unique:2
 i:1
n:5
last:4
:unique:2
 unique:1
 i:1
n:20
last:0
:unique:2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistyped the array index: use `array[i]` instead of `array[n]`.

Here is a simpler version:

```
int unique;
for (unique = 1; unique < n && array[unique] == array[unique - 1]; unique++) {
    continue;
}
printf("unique:%d\n", unique);
```

Comment: Which one? `(array[n] != last )` or `last = array[n];` ?

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it!

Comment: @chqrlie you are incrementing `i` i guess you wanted to increment `unique`?

Comment: @chqrlie I would increment unique, but that is producing incorrect results so I will stick with the correction of array[i] for now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Justin_Finland: indeed I meant to increment `unique`.  What incorrect result does it produce?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't ever modify n, the following happens in your loop:

```
if (array[n] != last ) {
    last = array[n];
```

In the first iteration, last is assigned array[n] and this stays this way.
Therefore, later on the if condition is always false.

Comment: Hard to tell since you never explained what your code is intended to do.  I could only explain so far why unique never can get incremented more than once.

Comment: Thank you, sir. The another user solved the issue. I appreciate it.

Comment: The code is intended to count the number of unique elements at the start of the array. It probably assumes the array is sorted.

Comment: Yes, chqrlie is correct. The array is already sorted. And the answer to make the change to i worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain how you read in your integers? Is your OUTPUT the result of running your code multiple times with different sets of integers?

```
 if (array[n] != last) {
```

If `array` is of size `n`, then accessing `array[n]` as you do in your if statement is dangerous, since an n-sized array is accessible through `array[0]`, `array[1]`, ..., `array[n-1]`. Did you mean to test `array[i]`?

```
last = array[n];
```

Same issue as above.

Your `n` is changing each iteration of the loop, which I assume is unintended.

The `printf` for `unique` is outside of the for loop.

Comment: Yes, I meant to test array[i]. Thank you!